# Vb.net Add years and then go to last day of the month

Tags: vb.net

I am using **DateAdd** function to add years to my existing date but I want to go to last date of that specific month.

I am using this code:

```
    Dim wr As Integer = Val(txtWar_per.Text)
    Dim ins_dt As Date = dtpInstall.Value
    Dim war_till As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, wr, dtpInstall.Value)
    dtpWar_till.Value = war_till
```

Output:

```
dtpinstall.value= 12/1/2012

txtWar_per.text=  2

dtpWar_till.value=12/1/2014
```

But I want **dtpWar_till.value**  as:

```
31/1/2014
```

Please resolve my problem early..
It's very, very, very urgent.

Comment: What if ins_dt is Feb 28, 2011 or Feb 29, 2012?  Anytime you are working with dates test leap values.

Comment: Hii.. i have checked for leap year but how 2 implement it??? The Code i m using gives 28th feb even for leap year..                                                   Code: 
If Date.IsLeapYear(war_till.Year) = True Then
  'dtpWar_till.Value = New DateTime(ins_dt.Year + wr, ins_dt.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(ins_dt.Year, ins_dt.Month))
Else
   dtpWar_till.Value = New DateTime(ins_dt.Year + wr,     ins_dt.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(ins_dt.Year, ins_dt.Month))
End If                                                                         Please suggest code for  commented line.

Comment: I added an answer that might help.

Comment: Thank yo very much... It works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test using leap years

```
    Dim tstDate1 As Date = #2/28/2011#
    Dim tstDate2 As Date = #2/29/2012#

    For numYears As Integer = 1 To 5
        'add years and set date to the first day of the month
        Dim newD As Date = New Date(tstDate1.Year + numYears, tstDate1.Month, 1)
        'then add days in month-1 to date
        newD = newD.AddDays(Date.DaysInMonth(newD.Year, newD.Month) - 1)
        'show it
        Debug.WriteLine(newD)


        newD = New Date(tstDate2.Year + numYears, tstDate2.Month, 1)
        newD = newD.AddDays(Date.DaysInMonth(newD.Year, newD.Month) - 1)
        Debug.WriteLine(newD)
    Next
```

Comment: Looks like an overkill to me, compared to other answers provided here.

Comment: Just trying to illustrate the point that leap years were not being considered in the answers.  I upvoted your modified answer.

Comment: The actual code to resolve the posters question is only two lines.

Answer (score 2):

Subtract the date minus one to get to the first day of the month, add a year and a month, then subtract another day to the last day of the previous month:

```
Dim war_till As Date = ins_dt.AddDays(1 - ins.dt.Day).AddMonths(13).AddDays(-1)
```

Subtracting days twice makes sure that it works with months with different number of days, e.g. from 2013-01-30 takes you to 2014-01-31 rather than 2014-03-01.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit more code, but somewhat more intuitive:

```
Dim year As Integer = ins_dt.Year + wr
Dim month As Integer = ins_dt.Month
dtpWar_till.Value = New DateTime(year, month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim war_till As Date = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,-1,DateAdd(DateInterval.Month,2,DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, wr, dtpInstall.Value)))
```