# Calculate the last day of the next month

Tags: vb.net, date

How to calculate the **last day of the next month** using vb.net?

Comment: You look for the next month, (ie adding 1 to the current month) and write a function getnextday that checks among the months, some care should be taken for month 2, it is an evil month !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vb.net Add years and then go to last day of the month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430686/vb-net-add-years-and-then-go-to-last-day-of-the-month)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try yo use `DaysInMonth` Function which returns the number of days in the required month.

**Example**

```
System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(2016,May)
```

This will return (31), so you can get the date format in addition to this number to get last day of this month.

Answer (score 2):

An other way is to get the first day of the month after and substract 1 day.

```
    Dim d As DateTime

    d = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2)
    d = New DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, 1).AddDays(-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you after the actual date....

You could use `DateSerial(Year, Month, 0)` this will return the last day of the month prior to the month entered.

Entering `DateSerial(2016, 07, 0)` will return "30/06/2016"

To get the last day of next month do `DateSerial(Now.Year, Now.Month + 2, 0)`

This works fine for February and also the year end as well (`DateSerial(2016, 3, 0)` returns "29/02/2016", `DateSerial(2016, 11 + 2, 0)` returns "31/12/2016")

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim N = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)
Dim D = New DateTime(N.Year, N.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(N.Year, N.Month))
```

`D` will have the last day of next month.