# VB.Net find last day of month with date format

Tags: vb.net, date

I am trying to find the last day of the month and compare it to today's date
I do NOT want the integer number I would like the result in this format "MM-dd-yyyy"
Date Picker will not work for this project
Here is the code I using but the process seems overly complicated concocting strings
Side note when today is after the 4th Tue I write True and the Last Day of the month to a DB
when today is after the last day of the month and the bool is now True I write the new last day of the new month and false to the DB

```
    Function FourthTueOfMonth(dt As Date) As Date
    Dim currDate = New Date(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1)
    Dim nTuesday = 0

    While nTuesday < 4
        If currDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday Then
            nTuesday += 1
        End If
        currDate = currDate.AddDays(1)
    End While

    Return New Date(dt.Year, dt.Month, currDate.Day - 1)

End Function
   Private Sub btnFindDate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFindDate.Click

    Dim tORf As Boolean = False
    Dim dateToday = Date.Today
    Dim dateFourthTue = (FourthTueOfMonth(Date.Today))

    tbFourthTue.Text = dateFourthTue.ToString("MMM-dd-yyyy")
    tbThree.Text = dateFourthTue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

    tbEndOFMonth.Text = Date.DaysInMonth(Date.Now.Year, Date.Now.AddMonths(0).Month).ToString

    Dim dToday As Date
    dToday = Date.Parse("10-01-2021")
    Dim dtY = dateToday.ToString("yyyy")
    Dim dtM = dateToday.ToString("MM")
    Dim eom As String = Date.DaysInMonth(Date.Now.Year, Date.Now.AddMonths(0).Month).ToString
    Dim dtALL As String
    dtALL = dtM & "-" & eom & "-" + dtY
    Dim testD As Date
    testD = Date.Parse(dtALL)

    If tORf = False And dToday > dateFourthTue Then
        MessageBox.Show("Today > Fourth Tue")
        'tORf = True'Write True
        'tbMessage.Text = tORf.ToString
    End If

    If tORf = True And dToday > testD Then
        MessageBox.Show("Today > End Of Last Month")
        'tORf = False write False
        'tbMessage.Text = tORf.ToString
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: This line of code is for testing ONLY dToday = Date.Parse("10-01-2021")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate the last day of the next month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805092/calculate-the-last-day-of-the-next-month)

Comment: @djv Yes that is the link I posted in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

You want to use today - not "now()" as that includes a time portion. While a date type only has date, you should consider if you have datetime, and either way, no need to introduce and use a value that includes both date and time such as now does.

I reocmmend this code:

```
    Dim dtToday As Date = Date.Today

    Dim dtEndOfMonth As Date = DateSerial(dtToday.Year, dtToday.Month + 1, 0)

    Debug.Print(dtToday)
    Debug.Print(dtEndOfMonth)
```

Output:
Today happens to be the 1st, but any date would work. This includes end of year, and even leap years.

```
2021-10-01
2021-10-31
```

So, this is a long time old trick - goes back to old VB6, and even old VBA code from 20 years ago.

So, we use date serial to produce a date, but if you use 0 for the day, then you get the previous day, and thus gets you the last day of the current month.

So we toss in year, month + 1, and 0 for the date - that results in the last day of the current month.

Comment: I do go back as far as VB6 but that is a long time ago I tried to use Today in place of Now but still get time attached and I assume your output was managed by adding format ("yyyy-M-dd")

Comment: Date.today does not include time, Date.Now does.  Today from what I can see also does not include time part.

Answer (score 3):

The solution provided by @Albert D. Kallal is great for Visual Basic since DateSerial is in the Visual Basic namespace in the DateAndTime class. Here is a solution that should work in both vb and C#.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dtToday As Date = Date.Today

    Dim dtEndOfMonth = New Date(dtToday.Year, dtToday.Month + 1, 1).AddDays(-1)

    Debug.Print(dtToday.ToString)
    Debug.Print(dtEndOfMonth.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Funny how that "kluge" going ALL the way back to even BEFORE .net days carries on to this day! We talking about even pre VB5 days! And I can confirm that this kluge does NOT work with vb.net new Date(y,m,0) (or DateTime in c#). so, this is a good habit,  and your suggesting will work for both c#, and vb.net.  Really amazing that this kluge has made it this far! - but, I would suggest to everyone here to use this solution. - upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

I hate to admit I might have gave up the search too quick
found the answer here
[Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805092/calculate-the-last-day-of-the-next-month)

Here is the code

```
    Dim dateToday = Date.Now.AddMonths(0)
    Dim dateEndOfMonth = New Date(dateToday.Year, dateToday.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(dateToday.Year, dateToday.Month))
    tbMsg.Text = dateEndOfMonth.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Code seems to be working ? 
I have seen suggestions to use this format for comparing dates
TEST DATES use this format yyyyMMdd Please comment if you can add to the answer

Comment: You use that format for comparison because it is sortable, having the longest period first (year), month in middle, and days at end. A variation such as yyyy-MM-dd is a standard date code in many parts of the world

Comment: So, you should actually mark your own question as a duplicate of the one you linked